# jenkins git webhook

Tags: php, git, jenkins, build, webhooks

I am using jenkins as a stand alone. an I want to trigger build when same commit pushed to git.
Jenkins GIT client plugin v1.0.2
Jenkins GIT plugin v1.2.0
Git server plugin v1.1
git-notes Plugin v0.0.4
ruby-runtime v0.10
GitHub API Plugin v1.34
GitHub plugin v1.5

this plugin I have installed in jenkins. and in git I have to put webhook url but which url I should put I don't know about that. and when I configure jenkins git web hook it asking me

I choose option Let Jenkins auto-manage hook URLs

in this there is
GitHub Credentials
i have fill this information in this
API URL:
Username:
Password:
API key:
but I don't know what is API URL,API key.
where can I get api url and ken in jenkins and which url I have to put in git webhook post.

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working using an OAuth token.  Steps to produce one can be seen here: http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/

General information on the github.com API can be seen here: http://developer.github.com/v3/